# How to numerically solve for the upper bound of a definite integral in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

Given the equation

[image: f(x) = int_{-infty}^]

For some given function `f(x)` where `gamma` is also given, how can you numerically solve for upper bound `u` in Matlab?

`f(x)` can be a placeholder for any model.

This is a root-finding and integration problem but with my lack of knowledge in Matlab, I'm still trying to figure out how it is done.

My initial solution is a brute force approach. Let's say we have

[image]

and `gamma = 0.8`, we can find the definite integral from `-inf` to `u` by extracting its integral from some very small value `u`, working our way up until we reach a result `gamma = 0.8`.

```
syms f(x)
f(x) = (1/(sqrt(6*pi)))*exp(-(x^2/6));  
gamma = 0.8;
u = -10;

res = int(f,x,-Inf,u);
while double(res) <= gamma
    u = u+0.1;
    res = int(f,x,-Inf,u);
end
fprintf("u is %f", u);
```

This solution is pretty slow and will definitely not work  all the time.

I set `u = 10` because looking at the graph of the function, we don't really get anything outside the interval [-5, 5].

Comment: What have you tried? Despite your 'lack of knowledge in MATLAB' I'm pretty sure you can write a [Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I also think you should be able to numerically integrate your example function `f` with `u` as a parameter and post the code as well.

Comment: You can look [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/trapz.html) or [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html) for numerical integration, and [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html) for finding the roots. Then, if you stumble on difficulties along the way, and after having actually tried, I invite you to update your question

Comment: Tried a brute force approach that can slowly solve the example function. I haven't tried utilizing root-finding methods yet.

Comment: Your approach will work only if your function `f` is positive (Else, the integral will not necessarily increase with `u`). Can you think of a way to rewrite your problem as a search for roots?

Comment: For now, I think it's fine to set the assumption that the function `f` is positive. In fact, let's just set `f` as what was mentioned above. Would there be a faster solution for this case?

Comment: If i denote by `S(u)` your integral, what can you say of the roots of `G(u) = S(u)-gamma`?

Comment: (By roots of `G` I mean the values of `u` for which `G = 0`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MATLAB Symbolic Math Toolbox (an addon you might need to install).
That way you can define yourself a "true" unknow variable x (not an array of x-values) and later integrate from negative infinity:

```
syms f(x)
f(x) = exp(2*x)  % an example function
gamma = int(f,x,-Inf,u)
```

This yields `gamma` as the integral from `-Inf` to `u`, after defining `f(x)` as a symbolic function and `u` as a scalar

Comment: The way I understand your code is that you are solving for `gamma`.  Is that correct? because in this case, `gamma` and `f(x)` are the inputs and we solve for `u`.

Comment: Yes you are right, I misunderstood your question earlier. Now you can solve this with `fzero` to find the root of a function. In your case you can define your function as the difference between the integral and `gamma`. That would be: `res = @(u) integral(f,-Inf,u) - gamma;`. To find the root of this function: `u_sol = fzero(res,1)`. Note that you do not need your symbolic function for this. So define `f` just like this: `f = @(x) exp(x)`